# alternatives to using ".this" for addActionListener? static context issues

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea

created login class for GUI, added all the GUI construction to a method so I can call it from my main class on startup. Calling method throws error "'GUILoginPage.this' cannot be referenced from a static context".

What are the work arounds for this? I understand the reasoning behind not being able to use .this but I haven't seen any solutions

```
public static void main() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");

    JTextField userIDField = new JTextField();
    JPasswordField userPasswordField = new JPasswordField();
    JLabel userIDLabel = new JLabel("Username:");
    JLabel userPasswordLabel = new JLabel("Password:");


    userIDLabel.setBounds(50, 100, 75, 25);
    userPasswordLabel.setBounds(50, 150, 75, 25);

    userIDField.setBounds(125, 100, 200, 25);
    userPasswordField.setBounds(125, 150, 200, 25);

    loginButton.setBounds(125, 200, 100, 25);
    loginButton.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(userIDLabel);
    frame.add(userPasswordLabel);
    frame.add(userIDField);
    frame.add(userPasswordField);
    frame.add(loginButton);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't contain "GUILoginPage.this"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` doesn't have any meaning in a static context. your main is Static so it means that there is no instance of a class to work with.

Here you will need to define and use your own action listener that will handle the button click, such as :

```
loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    performLogin();
  } 
} );
```

Comment: This worked, i can now reference the main method in my other class, but how do I code in the mouse click to the performLogin function?

Comment: the loginButton object should have a more specific listener, such as addClickEventListener that you can use to specifically listen to clic events, instead of the addActionListener